# Elliptic theta function wont evaluate

Tags: evaluation, special-functions

It appears that Mathematica wont evaluate the Jacobi theta functions when the last argument has a magnitude greater than 1, for example: `EllipticTheta[1, 1.5, 0.9]` evaluates, but
`EllipticTheta[1, 1.5, 1.1]` does not. What is going on here?

Comment: `q>=1` doesn't belong to the domain of the function, see e.g. `FunctionDomain[ EllipticTheta[1, 3/2, q], q]` yields `0 <= q < 1`.

Comment: From the [`documentation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticTheta.html), "The Subscript[\[CurlyTheta], a] are only defined within the unit q disk, |q| < 1; the unit disk forms a natural boundary of analyticity."

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828929/why-do-the-jacobi-theta-functions-have-a-natural-boundary